# SSH get list of php processes

Tags: php, ssh

How to get the list of php processes via ssh? and get the PID of php process that you need, how to see where is the process you need?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there a specific aspect of this task that you are having trouble with?

Comment: [Here is a post dealing with PHP and SSH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php) and [here is a post dealing with listing PHP processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335968/how-to-get-list-of-php-processes-running-on-server-with-php)

Comment: I've executed a long php process that is parsing data, but I need to stop it to make some edit at code, but I really don't know how to get php processes via SSH and stop them

Comment: Please try to search the site for existing answers before creating a new post.

Comment: I've searched, but still can't undestand how to do it, I'am stucked, I've tried those examples, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

you can get like this on unix shell

```
$ssh 10.2.8.67 "ps -ax | grep  php | cut -d' ' -f1"
```

Comment: the console just stops, but no data