# Php check if executable is running

Tags: php, process, executable

Is it possible in Php to check wether an executable is running or not,

some Pseudocode:

```
if(processExists("notepad.exe")
{
     echo "exists";
}
{
     echo "doesn't exists";
}
```

Comment: Isn't PHP web based? I'm pretty sure this isn't actually possible. You're going to have to use `C++`, if you want to accomplish this.

Comment: You would only be able to check server-side processes. JavaScript (client-side) isn't allowed that kind of access because of security.

Comment: well php can us shell_exec(), so I though that something like this may be possible

Comment: `shell_exec()` is on *the server*.

Comment: I mean you can run a local .exe with it

Comment: Local to the server, not the client. In your example notepad.exe *is not* going to be run on the PHP server.

Comment: And how would you check a process on a server?

Comment: [Here is one option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335968/how-to-get-list-of-php-processes-running-on-server-with-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would only be able to check server-side processes, where PHP is running. JavaScript (client-side) isn't allowed that kind of access because of security.

Comment: Of my own comment @CaelanGrgurovic

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using cli or want to check server-side processes.

For a Windows-specific solution, you can execute the shell command `tasklist` with the proper options (see `tasklist /?`). On Unix-based, you would use `ps`.

To execute a shell command under PHP, you can use [shell_exec()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [exec()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

**Warning:** Do not enter not sanitized user input in these commands.