# Don't run script if it's already running

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been completely unsuccessful finding an answer to this question. Hopefully someone here can help.

I have a PHP script (a WordPress template, to be specific) that automatically imports and processes images when a user hits it. The problem is that the image processing takes up a lot of memory, particularly if multiple users are accessing the template at the same time and initiating the image processing. My server crashed multiple times because of this.

My solution to this was to not execute the image-processing function if it was already running. Before the function started running, I would check a database entry named image_import_running to see if it was set to false. If it was, the function then ran. The very first thing the function did was set image_import_running to true. Then, after it was all finished, I set it back to false.

It worked great -- in theory. The site hasn't crashed since, I can tell you that. But there are two major problems with it:

1. If the user closes the page while it's loading, the script never finishes processing the images and therefore never sets image_import_running back to false. The template will never process images again until it's manually set to false.
2. If the script times out while it's processing images -- and that's a strong possibility if there are many images in the queue -- you have essentially the same problem as No. 1: the script never gets to the point where it sets image_import_running back to false.

To handle No. 1 (the first one of the two problems I realized), I added `ignore_user_abort(true)` to the script. Did it work? I don't know, because No. 2 is still an issue. That's where I'm stumped.

If I could ask the server whether the script was running or not, I could do something like this:

```
if($import_running && $script_not_running) {
    $import_running = false;
}
```

But how do I set that `$script_not_running` variable? Beats me.

I've shared this entire story with you just in case you have some other brilliant solution.

Comment: Don't do that on a page view. Do it in advance, or using a cron job.

Comment: fix the disease not the symptom

Comment: As others have suggested, it would be best to move the image processing out of the request itself. As an interim "fix", store a timestamp alongside `image_import_running` when a processing job begins (e.g., `image_import_commenced`). This is a very crude mechanism, but if you know the maximum time a job can run before timing out, the script can check whether that period of time has passed (e.g., if `image_import_running` is still true but the current time is more than 10 minutes since `image_import_commenced`, run the processing anyway).

Comment: Just to clarify here, the problem is that I have a cron job running that imports a huge number of posts, many of which have associated images. The images are enormous. We're only going to use a very small percentage of the posts, but the only way to tell whether or not we'll need one (without greatly increasing our editor's workload) is if a user tries to view it. That's why I'm importing the images on the first page view.

Comment: All this does give me an idea. Instead of processing the images when a user views the page, I could add the image URLs to an array (along with their associated post). Then I could run an occasional cron job that imports and processes anything in the array before clearing it out. Hey, that's not a bad idea -- thanks for the inspiration!

Comment: @plasmid87 add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using 
`ignore_user_abort(true);` it will continue to run even if the person leaves and closes the browser.

you might also want to put a number instead of true false in the db record and set a maximum number of processes that can run together

Comment: This is a good idea but it depends on what CGI interface is being used by the webserver. Many implementations have a "hard timeout" that cannot be overridden with `ignore_user_abort(true)`; the process will be forcibly killed after the timeout period elapses.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, it would be best to move the image processing out of the request itself.

As an interim "fix", store a timestamp alongside `image_import_running` when a processing job begins (e.g., `image_import_commenced`). This is a very crude mechanism, but if you know the maximum time that a job can run before timing out, the script can check whether that period of time has elapsed.

e.g., if `image_import_running` is still true but the current time is more than 10 minutes since `image_import_commenced`, run the processing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What about setting a transient with an expiry time that would throttle the operation?

```
if(!get_transient( 'import_running' )) {
  set_transient( 'import_running', true, 30 ); // set a 30 second transient on the import.
  run_the_import_function();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather store the job into database flagging it pending and set a cron job to execute the processing one job at a time.

Answer (score 0):

> **Warning:** This approach contains a race condition

For Me i use just this simple idea with a  text document. for example run.txt file
in the top script use :

```
if((file_get_contents('run.txt') != 'run'){ // here the script will work
$file = fopen('run.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($file, 'run');
fclose('run.txt');
}else{
exit(); // if it find 'run' in run.txt the script will stop
}
```

And add this in the end of your script file

```
$file = fopen('run.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($file, ''); //will delete run word for the next try ;)
fclose('run.txt');
```

That will check if script already work by checking `runt.txt` contents 
if run word exist in `run.txt` it will not run

Comment: This contains a race condition. Two processes can both check the contents of `run.txt` at the same time, both see it's empty, and both write to it. And if a program dies it won't delete the contents of `run.txt` and nothing will ever run.

Answer (score 0):

Running a cron would definitively be a better solution. Idea to store url in a table is a good one.

To answer to the original question, you may run a ps auxwww command with exec (Check this page: [How to get list of running php scripts using PHP exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182558/how-to-get-list-of-running-php-scripts-using-php-exec) ) and move your function in a separated php file.

```
exec("ps auxwww|grep myfunction.php|grep -v grep", $output);
```

Comment: Any process mentioning `myfunction.php` will trip this. For example: `vim myfunction.php` or `php /a/totally/different/myfunction.php`.

Answer (score -2):

Just add following on the top of your script.

```
<?php
    // Ensures single instance of script run at a time.
    $fileName = basename(__FILE__);
    $output = shell_exec("ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $fileName | wc -l");
    //echo $output; 
    if ($output > 2)
    {
        echo "Already running - $fileName\n";
        exit;   
    }

    // Your php script code.
?>
```