# Using php to detect and output if a specific program is running

Tags: php, linux, bash, output

Basically I'd like to know of a very simple method for making a php script check if a specific program is running on my nix box.

Something like :

```
<?php

#some detection function here.

if($detectprogram == 1){ 
echo("It's running.");
}
else{
echo("It's not running.");
}
?>
```

Or even if I had to execute the program via a .sh (as I already do) and an -outputphp /path/to/htdocs/. Or similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this?

```
exec("ps auxwww|grep sample.php|grep -v grep", $output);
```

Source: [How to get list of running php scripts using PHP exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182558/how-to-get-list-of-running-php-scripts-using-php-exec)